# Rendering content based off Next.js router.query causes re-render and flicker?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, url-routing

I have a page that uses `router.query` to determine what content to render.

However, it looks like the page will always render without `router.query` first before loading the `router.query` code in resulting in the page "flickering"

Here is a simple stackblitz to show what I mean: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-jvtyrm?file=pages/index.js

Relevant code bits:

```
export default function Home() {
  const router = useRouter();
  const isRouterQuery = router.query.foo ? true : false;

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <main className={styles.main}>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (isRouterQuery) {
              window.location.href = '/';
            } else {
              window.location.href = '/?foo=bar';
            }
          }}
        >
          Toggle between homepage and homepage with router.query
        </button>
        {isRouterQuery ? (
          <h1 className={styles.title}>Router Header</h1>
        ) : (
          <h1 className={styles.title}>
            Welcome to <a href="https://nextjs.org">Next.js!</a>
          </h1>
        )}

// ...
```

If you click the button to toggle from `/` to `/?foo=bar`, you'll see that the initial render shows `Welcome to Next.js` for a split second before re-rendering to show the `Router Header` content.

How do I get rid of this initial flicker?

Answer (score 2):

If a page does not have data fetching methods, the flicker will always occur on the page's first load because when the page gets pre-generated on the server by Next.js `router.query` is an empty object.

From the [`next/router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) documentation:

> `query`: `Object` - The query string parsed to an object. It will be
> an empty object during prerendering if the page doesn't have [data
> fetching
> requirements](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching).
> Defaults to `{}`

In your case, you're also experiencing the flicker when clicking the button because you use `window.location.href` to navigate between pages, and that causes a full page reload rather than a client-side navigation.

To fix the issue, just replace the `window.location.href` statements with `router.push` calls. This way Next.js can properly execute a client-side navigation, which does not trigger the flickering.

```js
<button
    onClick={() => {
        if (isRouterQuery) {
            router.push('/');
        } else {
            router.push('/?foo=bar');
        }
    }}
>
    Toggle between homepage and homepage with router.query
</button>
```

Comment: Super useful, it's weird but I fixed the problem just by adding `getServerSideProps` even when my page won't need any SSR.

Comment: Indeed, adding `getServerSideProps` means the page will now have data fetching requirements so the `router.query` will always be set, and the issue does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Router now has an `isReady` boolean. I was able to prevent content flashing by checking for it first.

From the docs:

> isReady: boolean - Whether the router fields are updated client-side and ready for use. Should only be used inside of useEffect methods and not for conditionally rendering on the server.

In your case you could do

```js
  const router = useRouter();
  const [routerReady, setRouterReady] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    setRouterReady(router.isReady)
  }, [router.isReady])

  const isRouterQuery = router.query.foo ? true : false;
```

And check for it in the template

```
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            if (routerReady && isRouterQuery) {
              window.location.href = '/';
            } else {
              window.location.href = '/?foo=bar';
            }
          }}
        >
          Toggle between homepage and homepage with router.query
        </button>
```